# Do you know, if it's possible to set backups only for particular databases in rds instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

let's have a scenario - I have RDS with 5 DBs on it ... 3 are main with production data and 2 are data warehouses ... those 3 main are not so big, so the backup can run pretty fast (so it's not a big impact on customers) ... but data warehouse can hold up to gigabytes of records and can be painful to backup ... does AWS doing backups on RDS level or DB level?

Comment: This question should be asked under DB SE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Creating a DB Snapshot - Amazon Relational Database Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_CreateSnapshot.html):

> Amazon RDS creates a storage volume snapshot of your DB instance, backing up the entire DB instance and not just individual databases.

Thus, the Snapshot function does a backup of the **entire database instance**. It does *not* support backup of only selected logical databases within the database instance.

You can, of course, use traditional backup software to backup selected databases within the database instance, as long as the software connects via SQL rather than expecting to run on the same physical host.

From [Working With Backups - Amazon Relational Database Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithAutomatedBackups.html):

> The first snapshot of a DB instance contains the data for the full DB instance. Subsequent snapshots of the same DB instance are incremental, which means that only the data that has changed after your most recent snapshot is saved.

So, if you have a lot of data but it doesn't change much, the backups could be quick quick and small.

Comment: And regardless, a snapshot does not interfere with the running server.